# Do the Tyrells know (or suspect) where Sansa is?

Tags: a-song-of-ice-and-fire

Note: this refers to book canon only.

The Tyrells worked with Littlefinger to

> assassinate Joffrey

at the purple wedding. As this is taking place, Sansa is spirited away by Littlefinger to the Vale, the endgame of this being that Sansa marries Harry the Heir and unites the Vale with the North.

Not long before Sansa's marriage to Tyrion, there was a Tyrell plot to have Sansa taken to Highgarden to marry the Tyrell heir Willas, thus uniting the Stark house with the Tyrells.

Considering that the Tyrells were the only ones who knew what was going on at the purple wedding, and that Sansa mysteriously disappeared at the exact same time, were they aware that it was Littlefinger that took her, or is there any evidence that they might have an indication?

And considering that they had very recently expressed an interest in Sansa's marriage prospects, if they know Sansa's whereabouts, are they also aware of the Vale marriage plot?

Comment: Haven't read the books but from your explanation this seems like a classic LF double cross to get what he wants i.e. more power- in this case in the Vale and the North.

Comment: The books change quite a lot the arc of Sansa, she is not even married to Bolton but keep the secret identity of Alayne Stone

Comment: I won't answer because I can't remember for sure and aren't going to dig up quotes, but I remember the Tyrell's try and offer to help Sansa but she refuses. Eventually she accepts Littlefinger's help instead. I think his plan for Sansa was separate from the Tyrell one.

Answer (score -2):

In the books, there is no indication that the Tyrells were connected in the assassination plot. But it makes no matter. Sansa is the key to the North. It is not shown in the series, but in the books, they wanted her to be married off to the their house's heir Garlan Tyrell (Loras's brother. Not Loras though, he is in the Kingsguard).

The lords and houses would do anything to gain power. Especially something like North, oh, boy! that is a grand price and Tyrells would never have let that slip through their fingers again. First time Sansa was married off quickly to Tyrion. They had little or no option or simply unaware of the arrangements Tywin made. And Tywin, as soon as he came to know about the Tyrell plot, moved quickly and married her to his son. In fact, if I remember correctly, they were absent in her wedding with Tyrion.

If they had known about Sansa's whereabouts they would not have sat quietly, especially after the death of Tywin, disappearance of Tyrion and the fall of Cersei. They would have tried to bring her in, prove her innocence, and marry her off to their heir.

In the TV series, they do not show the importance of the family or inheritance. Simply seizing a castle does not give the true power to rule over people. One must have a legitimate claim and Sansa had that for the entire North.

So in essence the probability is less that they know about the Littlefinger's sub plot.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the Tyrell's were involved in the plot in the books too. Your second point seems a bit tangential to the question. Your third paragraph is purely opinion based with no evidence - would they want a war with the Vale? Your fourth point seems completely wrong and also tangential. Your final conclusion is probably right but you have no evidence to back it up.

Comment: We only get it from Sansa's POV, but it's heavily implied that Lady Olenna was behind Joffrey's poisoning-- Sansa is told as much by Littlefinger himself IIRC.